# How to make Quartz Scheduler in Eclipse work?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm just starting to self-study Quartz Scheduler and I'm really having a hard time in making it work and compile this program

```
public class SimpleExample implements Job
     {
            public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {

                System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");     
          }
```

}

can you help me?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `eclipse` is essential to make this work. To make use of `quartz`:

1. Download & install Quartz.
2. Configure it.
3. Start using it in your app.

Hope [this](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/) guides you well.

Posting your stacktrace can help in tracking down the root-cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following is some Pseudo code you can run for testing and getting Understanding.

```
public class QuartzTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
            Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

            JobDetail job = newJob(HelloWord1.class)
            .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
                    .repeatForever())            
            .build();

        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger




            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

            scheduler.shutdown();

        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the external jar files that I will be requiring. I downloaded the back from Terracotta and I do not know what to do with the files.

Comment: Put [this](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.7/quartz-2.1.7.jar) jar in your classpath in eclipse and your are done :-)

Comment: Nicole, Shinchan has suggested the right jar to be configured and just check the magic of the scheduler. You can easily configure this jar with eclipse.

Comment: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.7/quartz-2.1.7.jar is the URL given by Shinchan

Comment: I tried the jar. I got errors saying "a child component failed during start"

I encounter this error when my servlet can't find my jrxml in my previous dynamic project.